# Find count of smaller no of elements in an array and the solution needs to be 2n

Tags: php, data-structures

Hi i am stuck with a problem where in i have to find out the count of smaller no of element in an array i have implemented what we call as a brute force method but this isn't the optimised solution, can anyone help me out with the optimise solution for the code below

```
<?php
    function find_small_count($arr){
        $no_count = []; 
        foreach ($arr as $key => $value){
            $no_count[$key] = 0;
            foreach ($arr as $key1 => $value){
                if ($arr[$key1] < $arr[$key]) {
                    $no_count[$key]++;
                }
            }
        }
        return $no_count;
    }   
    print_r(find_small_count(['8','1','2','2','5']));
?>
```

> Where in the expected Output should be [4,0,1,1,3]

Comment: how you have mapped your array to the result ?

Comment: i haven't mapped the result onto array, that's what i get as a result, i hope i am getting your question right.

Comment: I just want to know how the input['8','1','2','2','5'] has this expected result [4,0,1,1,3]. ia m not able to understand output.

Comment: The loop starts with index 0 so the number is selected is 8 it goes through all the elements in the array and checks for how many numbers are smaller than it. i.e 8 and the count is stored in an array, for 8 the count will be 4 similarly for 1 the count will be 0 for 2 the count will be 1 and for 5 it will be 3 , hope this clears your doubt.

Comment: you can use merge sot. It has complexity of O(nlog(n)). In the sorted array you can get count of smaller element in O(n).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have three solutions for you. Let me explain

[Working code sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d4254232882c80a76c7bcf1651a761f22187a92f)

#### Solution 1

Use [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter) to return only qualified elements and then count the filtered array to get the count.

```php
## Solution 1:

function find_small_count($arr)
{
    $response = [];
    foreach ($arr as $valueToSearch) {
        $filtered = array_filter($arr, function ($value) use ($valueToSearch) {
            return $value < $valueToSearch;
        });
        $response[] = ['valueToSearch' => $valueToSearch, 'count' => count($filtered)];
        
    }
    return $response;
}
print_r(find_small_count(['8', '1', '2', '2', '5']));
```

#### Solution 2

`Sort` the array in ascending order. When doing so your array has all numbers lesser than the current element appearing before it (in the array). Therefore the `key` for the array will be the count of all those numbers that are less than the current value, excluding the current number (keys start with 0).

Exception will be when a number appears twice, like `2` in your case. If we were to use `key` as the `count` in your case the `first 2` will have `count 1` and `second 2` will have `count 2`, which is incorrect. Do note that the `first 2` does give you the correct count.

To avoid this we can use [`array_unique`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique) and remove the duplicates. That will leave you with only one 2 in your response (the first one) and will give you the correct count.

You may think what about `5`. For that we can fallback on the behavior of `array_unique` to preserve the keys. Hence even after `array_unique` `5` will retain its `key`, ie. `3`. And our objective is accomplished. The only side effect is that the response will be `[4,0,1,3]` instead of `[4,0,1,1,3]`. So if that works you can use this method.

```
function find_small_count_two($arr){
    $response = [];
    sort($arr);
    $arrUniqueAndSorted = array_unique($arr);
    foreach ($arrUniqueAndSorted as $key => $value){
        $response[] = ['valueToSearch' => $value, 'count' => $key];
    }
    return $response;
}
print_r(find_small_count_two(['8', '1', '2', '2', '5']));
```

#### Solution 3

Use [`array_search`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search). From the docs

> Searches the array for a given value and returns the first corresponding key if successful

Same logic as Solution 2 but this one avoids `array_unique`

```
function find_small_count_three($arr){
    $response = [];
    sort($arr);
    foreach ($arr as $valueToCount){
        $count =array_search($valueToCount, $arr);
        $response[] = ['valueToSearch' => $valueToCount, 'count' => $count];
    }
    return $response;
}
```

Comment: I would prefer Solution 3. Clean and simple. Hacky though! First solution will work in all cases.